# Concurrent usage of golang mongo's gridsf driver

Tags: mongodb, go, gridfs

I am going to use golang gridfs driver, and [here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs#Bucket.DownloadToStream) I have statement in docs:
"If this download requires a custom read deadline to be set on the bucket, it cannot be done concurrently with other read operations operations on this bucket that also require a custom deadline."

And same for write deadline.

But what will happen if I do? And how should I manage concurrent requests to gridfs? Should forget about timeouts?

I did some research on docs, libs srcs and website but found nothing.

Comment: Plain and simple: last deadline set wins.